# Use cases of keyword using in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, using

I know `using` in C++11 behaves same as `typedef`. I have this code and found different use cases:

```
template<typename T, int a>
class Base
{
public:
     std::vector<T> noise_(a);
     using VectorType = std::vector<T>;
     virtual VectorType getVector() const
     {
        return noise_;
     }
protected:
     VectorType noise_;
};

template<typename T, int a> 
class Derived : public Base<T,a>
{
public:
    using Base<T,a>::noise_;
    using VectorType = typename Base<T,a>::VectorType; 
    using Base<T,a>::getVector;
};
```

Here, `using` is used in 3 different way. What is the purpose of the following line (`noise_` is a protected member of the base class):

```
using Base<T,a>::noise_;
```

Same for:

```
using Base<T,a>::getVector;
```

Comment: cppreference is a really good reference to use if you want know know about a language feature: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: There is one significant difference between `using` and `typedef`: Only the former can be used for [alias templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, when the base class depends on a template parameter, its scope is not inspected to resolve names. Hence, you cannot refer to `noise_` in `Derived` using just `noise_`. You should either write `this->noise_`, or introduce the name with `using`.

Comment: can you please this line, "when the base class depends on a template parameter, its scope is not inspected to resolve names".

Comment: @TonyParker, could I please what?

Comment: explain this line

Comment: @TonyParker, `Derived` has a template parameter `T` (let's omit `a` for brevity) and is derived from `Base<T>` that depends on that same `T`. Public and protected members of `Base<T>` are visible inside `Derived`, but you can't access them using just their names, because the compiler will not look into `Base<T>` scope without your special instruction. You should either write `this->name` or `using Base<T>::name`. If `Base<T>` does not depend on `T` (say, you derive from `Base<int>`), this rule does not apply and `Base` members will be accessible inside `Derived` without `this->` or `using`.